# How to allow users to search only their posts using Elastic Search with Searchkick on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I want users to be able to search only their posts and not show the posts created by other users. How exactly would I do that? I'm using `Elastic Search` with `Searchkick` gem.

I tried this but it is still showing posts from other users:

**posts controller**

```
@posts = current_user.posts.search params[:search]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), the following should work:

```
Post.search params[:search], where: {user_id: current_user.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a where clause to only search the post of the user

```
@posts = current_user.posts.where(user_id: current_user.id).search(params[:search])
```

Comment: Tried this and restarted both rails and elastic search server. It didn't work its still showing other users posts in the search.

Comment: i'm assuming that the posts model have a user_id field, am i right?

Comment: Yes, i have page showing all the users posts and that works fine using current_user.posts for some reason it doesn't work when searching.

Comment: have you seen what is receiving the search as a param?

Comment: Do you mean this?   User Load SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Comment: @EliteViper777 not exactly, but still works. i don't see the posts in the query search, maybe there's a problem with the gem, have you try using another like ransack? it's super easy to use, here's the link to the gem repo: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack and the link to a railscasts video to understand how use it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack