# Find users items through association using Elasticsearch with Searchkick on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, has-many, searchkick

I have to search books, users have books through authors need to be able to search only their books without showing other users books.

**books model**

```
has_many :authors
has_many :users, through: :authors
```

I tried to search as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888407/how-to-allow-users-to-search-only-their-posts-using-elastic-search-with-searchki) but it did not work.

```
@Books = Book.search "*", where: { user_id: current_user.id}
```

I believe that it did not work because `books` model does not have `user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few ways you could do this.
Here's one: **Search through the Books Index in searchkick, but only return the books whose id matches one of the users book_ids**

**user model**

```
# assuming you have:
has_many :books, through: :authors
```

**in the controller**

```
# change your where clause to filter based on book id
@Books = Book.search "*", where: { id: current_user.book_ids}
```